# Fast submatrix lookup with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

I am writing an implementation of Bridson's Poisson disc sampling ([https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~rbridson/docs/bridson-siggraph07-poissondisk.pdf](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Erbridson/docs/bridson-siggraph07-poissondisk.pdf)) for Python.

A feature of this sampling is that there is a set minimal distance between samples, and it avoids clustering. The neighbour lookup for new candidate points exploits this feature, and uses a background grid to speed up searches.

The background grid consists of a boolean grid `M` that stores `True` for non-empty cells and `False` otherwise, and a grid of points `P` that stores the exact coordinates. Both of them are implemented as n-dimensional `numpy` arrays.

The grid size `cellsize` is selected in such a way that there is at most one sample in each grid cell, and then you only have to check a few of the nearest rows and columns.

For now, I use the following procedure for checking if the point `p` is close to any of the existing points:

```
    def in_neighborhood(p, n=2):
        indices = (p/cellsize).astype(int)
        indmin = np.maximum(indices-n, np.zeros(ndim, dtype=int))
        indmax = np.minimum(indices+n+1, gridsize)
        if M[tuple(indices)]:
            return True
        for offset in np.ndindex(tuple(indmax - indmin)):
            indcur = tuple([sum(x) for x in zip(indmin,offset)])
            if M[indcur] and squared_distance(p, P[indcur]) < squared_radius:
                return True
        return False
```

This eats up a lion's share of the execution time (> 90%). I suspect the way I've implemented the `for` cycle here is really suboptimal, but I don't really get how to extract a submatrix otherwise, when I don't know the number of dimensions beforehand. Any help is appreciated.

The complete code and a Jupyter notebook with some usage examples is located at https://github.com/diregoblin/poisson_disc_sampling

Comment: I believe this boils down to a tricky submatrix of unknown dimension, possibly with some reshaping... Can you made an example in dimention, say 3, with the warning this needs to be generalized?

Comment: @user3184950 What this boils down to:
- We have a ndim-dimensional np.array ``M``
- We know two sets of indices ``indmin`` and ``indmax``, each a ``1 x ndim`` np.array
- We want to look at each value in a rectangular sub-array with corners at ``M[indmin[0], indmin[1], ... indmin[ndim-1]]`` and ``M[indmax[0], indmax[1], ... indmax[ndim-1]]`` in an efficient way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Slicing is the way:

The dimensionality makes it a bit tricky. In the end, the overhead for preparing the sliced into an array was well worth it. Maybe a further optimization would be possible if you knew the dimensions beforehands. It shouldn't be too much of a difference.
As an interesting part, this made the M matrix almost redundant - it is only used to check if the point itself is worth the try since the rest of the multiplication is sped up drastically by the slice.

#### Update:

I re-introduced the M check as per comment and also used the `np.square` instead of `np.power` as op mentioned.

Time after the np.power > np.square transition:

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     1    0.196    0.196    5.906    5.906 (Bridson_sampling)
```

The updated function:

```
def in_neighborhood(p, n=2):
    indices = (p / cellsize).astype(int)
    indmin = np.maximum(indices - n, np.zeros(ndim, dtype=int))
    indmax = np.minimum(indices + n + 1, gridsize)
    if M[tuple(indices)]:
        return True
    a = []
    for i in range(ndim):
        a.append(slice(indmin[i], indmax[i]))
    if np.any(np.logical_and(M[tuple(a)], np.sum(np.square(p - P[tuple(a)]), axis=ndim) < squared_radius)):
        return True
```

The result seems to be the same, however I would still recommend looking over it - I could've made an error. The resulting time is ~5 times faster. Still not all that fast, however I think that I can live with ~120K calls in 6.8 seconds for now.

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.207    0.207    6.802    6.802 (Bridson_sampling)
   123689    3.163    0.000    4.818    0.000 (in_neighborhood)
507833/507831    0.224    0.000    2.220    0.000 implement_array_function}
   503091    0.439    0.000    1.610    0.000 (_wrapreduction)
   142170    0.310    0.000    1.469    0.000 (in_limits)
```

#### Old part.

I will leave the rest of the answer for the completenes sake and for the amusement. Learning from failures.

I've spent last few hours digging through your code to no avail. I managed to shave ~3% of execution time which is probably an error of a profiler and I'm not happy. During the process, I became a bit confused by several things so I'm going to ask about them, maybe it can help a little?  Honestly, I don't know.

In the algorithm that you have in github, while generating the spherical sample it doesn't seem like you are excluding the inner sphere. This might add in some unnecessary iterations to your algorithm. Is this intended?

Quoting from the source material:

> While the active list is not empty, choose a random index
> from it (say i). Generate up to k points chosen uniformly from the
> spherical annulus between radius r and 2r around xi. For each
> point in turn, check if it is within distance r of existing samples
> (using the background grid to only test nearby samples). If a point
> is adequately far from existing samples, emit it as the next sample
> and add it to the active list. If after k attempts no such point is
> found, instead remove i from the active list.

Another thing: As I understand it, the author suggests to:

0. Initialize the list with a point.
1. Take a random point from the list if nonempty
2. Set k = 0
3. Take a random neighbor point as a sample.
4. If the point is a suitable candidate, add it into the list
5. Increase k
6. If k = 30 and no point is found, remove the original point from the list.
7. Go back to 1

This interpretation stems from the:

> 3 Analysis
> Step 2 is executed exactly 2N−1 times to produce N samples: each
> iteration either produces a new sample and adds it to the active list,
> or removes an existing sample from the active list. Each iteration of
> step 2 takes O(k) time, and since k is held constant (typically quite
> small) the algorithm is linear.

Where the author states that in each iteration you either add a point or remove one. He says nothing about adding multiple points at once. (Now that I think about it, I'm not certain how does this 2N fit with the fact that he can run into a point more than once - which he will. Overall I'm rather confused by the algorithm description. Maybe that's just me being tired though.)

What you are doing is slightly different since you always take full 30 samples, try them all out, then delete the original element. From the output it seems to generate reasonably similar result from what the author claims.

Also, for the clarity sake, what is N? I assume that its the number of points to be generated.

- There are ~5K points generated in the result
- The `in_neighborhood` function gets called ~122K times
- This is well within the bounds that the author claims (2N * k)

One observation:
Many of the computations are redundant since the P[indcur] is often zero - at least at the beginning since I wasn't patient enough to wait for later prints. So maybe some kind of caching during the computation could help.
However as I just tested, the tuple casting is rather fast so the dimensionality most likely isn't the problem I thought at the beginning.

Another possible thing that comes to mind is that a lot of floating point operations could be one of the possible causes.

Comment: Thank you for your interest.

>In the algorithm that you have in github, while generating the spherical sample it doesn't seem like you are excluding the inner sphere. This might add in some unnecessary iterations to your algorithm. Is this intended?
You are correct, the inner sphere should be excluded. It's included mainly because I couldn't come up with a way to uniformly sample from a n-dim annulus. However in 3D it's just 1/8 of samples, and it further drops to 1/16 in 4D etc. I plan to improve this in the future.

cont'd...

Comment: You are also correct that the implementation of sampling is slightly different. I assume that drawing all the samples in a vectorized way with numpy is faster than drawing it one by one. The end result should be similar to the original algorithm, since both approaches achieve the same sampling from the area between ``1*r`` and ``2*r`` away from existing points. The total number or macro iterations should be smaller in my implementation than in the single-sample-per-iteration variant, though.

Comment: Thank you for the observation about P[indcur]. Zero in this value should correspond to a False value in M[indcur], and I assumed that the if-clause ``if M[indcur] and squared_distance(p, P[indcur]) < squared_radius:``  would be optimized away for False values. 
Probably this isn't the case and it still calculates the distance? If that's the case, maybe nested if's will be a bit faster.

Comment: Also, ``N`` in Bridson's paper is the minimum number of points generated by ``2N - 1`` iterations. The algorithm may actually generate more points from ``2N - 1`` iterations, this would correspond to a non-empty queue at the end.

Then again, it's possible that the algorithm won't be able to go all ``2 N - 1``, because it can run out of space. Practically, what's important from this analysis is that the algorithm runs linearly with the number of accepted samples.

Comment: Also, I've just tried a single-accept variation, and it's about 30% slower for the 3D case.

Comment: Ah, it could be. I forgot to check the M[indcur] state in those cases. AND in python is a short - circuit so M[indcur] being false would prevent the second part of the evaluation. That is true.

Comment: Slicing is almost a perfect solution, thanks! It speeds things up about x5 for me.

There is one issue with ignoring ``M``, and that's the behaviour close to zero. The distance is also checked for empty cells in ``P``, so your solution acts as if there is already a sample at zero, so it never accepts samples there... To fix this, I filled ``P`` with NaN's instead of zeros initially, since for NaN's ``<`` will always return false. This way, samples close to zero can also be drawn.

Also, replacing ``np.power()`` with ``np.square()`` wins additional 8%.

I've updated the solution on Github

Comment: Adding the M check is rather straightforward and can be done with slicing as well. Actually I had it included a while ago, however I somewhat thought that it is for the speedup only and since there was no speedup, I removed it once again ^^.

Comment: Hi Shamis, I'm working on including this sampling into `scipy`. Can you give your permission to reuse your code, and how would you like to be credited? (Apparently the default SO licence isn't compatible with `scipy`)

Comment: Hello Dinergoblin, feel free to reuse my code. If you feel like crediting me, It would be nice, though it isn't strictly necessary ;-)