# How to equally disperse items throughout a list

Tags: python, arrays, list

I am making a platformer with pygame where in each round you have to run to end of the level without getting hit by bullets from the enemies in your way. The level is in the form of a list. Basically what I want is to have enemies dispersed throughout the level with about an equal distance apart from each other. My first idea was to have a radius for each enemy, and have the program randomly disperse the enemies in a way that none of the enemies are overlapping each others' radii. A good way to think about it is like molocules in a closed space. I think it would be a good idea if the program randomly placed the enemies, checks if the enemies are colliding with another enemy radius, and displaces them accordingly.

I tried making a program that counts the amount of empty spaces, dividing the amount of empty spaces by a random amount to get the amount of enemy spaces, then inserting 'E' (enemy) using those variables.

```
    def shuffle_map(self, difficulty):
        empty_level_map = [
        '6--------------------------------------------------------------7',
        'LXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXI',
        '9______________________________________________________________8',
        'M                                                              O',
        'M                                                              O',
        'M      P                                                       O',
        'M                                                              O',
        'M                                                              O',
        '6--------------------------------------------------------------7',
        'LXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXI',
        '9______________________________________________________________8']
        self.level_data = []
        empty_val = 0
        for line in empty_level_map:
            line = list(line)
            for n, char in enumerate(line):
                if char.isspace():
                    empty_val += 1
        random_space = random.randint(2, 4)
        enemy_space = (empty_val / random_space)
        place = 1
        for line in empty_level_map:
            line = list(line)
            for n, char in enumerate(line):
                if char.isspace():
                    place += 0.1
                    if empty_val / round(place) == empty_val / random_space:
                        line[n] = "E"
                        place = 1
                        random_space = random.randint(9, 11)

            self.level_data.append("".join(line))
```

The results are ok, but as I add more and more enemies you start to see clusters of them all in one place. I want the enemies to be equally dispersed throughout the level, and two enemies should never be close to each other.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You might want to look into [Poisson Disc Sampling](https://www.jasondavies.com/poisson-disc/).

Comment: Poisson Disc: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66047540/4014959 & https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.qmc.PoissonDisk.html

Comment: Poisson Disc sampling gives beautiful results, but it is a fairly sophisticated technique, and it may be a bit overwhelming to write such code yourself if you're still fairly new to coding.

Answer (score 0):

You could think of it from a different angle.  If you placed the enemies at their minimal distance and then randomly distribute the remaining space over the gaps between them, you would get your guaranteed minimum spacing with a more regular distribution of the random gaps between enemies:

```
import random
from itertools import accumulate

enemyCount   = 10
totalSpace   = 1000
minimumSpace = 20

spread      = [random.randrange(totalSpace) for _ in range(enemyCount+1)]
totalGaps   = totalSpace - minimumSpace*(enemyCount-1)
totalSpread = sum(spread)
positions   = [ i*minimumSpace + int(gap*totalGaps/totalSpread) 
               for i,gap in enumerate(accumulate(spread[:-1]))]

print(positions)
[146, 202, 238, 405, 462, 542, 637, 693, 857, 892]

print([b-a for a,b in zip(positions,positions[1:])])
[56, 36, 167, 57, 80, 95, 56, 164, 35]
```

In short, randomly distribute gaps rather than randomly placing enemies.

If you need this in 2D, repeat the same process for each axis independently.

Comment: I am really an amateur at python so I didn't understand the code. I tried using the code and found that all the number are close to each other, so I tried changing the minimum value but it still didn't work.  Basically what I want is given a list with enemies, it should start form the beginning and check if the first to enemies are too close to each other. If so, the index of the first enemy should move back as far as I want the enemies to be apart. Once I get figure this out, I will repeat with 2D like you said.

Comment: Now that I think about it, the molocule anology was not a good way to think about this

Comment: Another thing is that I first have to sort the list from least to greatest for this to work.